# Как заставить макрос издавать звук при изменении значения в ячейке?

Tags: excel, vba, value, macro

Сделал парсер в Excel который обновляется каждую минуту и хотелось бы что б макрос издавал звук при изменении данных в второй строке.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
 If (старое значение ячейки <> новое значение той же ячейки) Then
 ExecuteExcel4Macro "sound.play(,""C:\Windows\Media\Windows NotifyEmail.wav"")"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: *что б макрос издавал звук* - оператор `Beep`

Comment: Проблема в том что я не знаю как заставить макрос издавать звук именно при изменении значения в ячейке.

Comment: При изменении значения в ячейке? Тогда описать глобальную переменную и в ней хранить предыдущее значение, именно его сравнивать с новым значением и заменять на новое значение после Beep. Если контролировать нужно целую строку, то проще где-нибудь на листе, в сторонке, держать копию проверяемой строки и точно так же проверять и обновлять в макросе.

Answer (score 0):

Вернемся на шаг назад (`Undo`), запишем в переменную предыдущее значение ячейки, вернемся обратно, сравним предыдущее и текущее значения:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim testvalue As Long
        
        If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .EnableEvents = False: End With
    
            Application.Undo
            testvalue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            If testvalue <> Target.Value Then Beep
            
            With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .EnableEvents = True: End With
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Код работает при ручной смене данных. У меня обновляется таблица с павер куери, оно его просто не видит)

Comment: Так опишите нормально полностью все условия, а то выдаете по одной новости...